# How to test localhost connection to smtp.office365.com or smtp.gmail.com using TLS on port 587

Tags: php, email, ssl, mamp, tls1.2

I am working locally on OS X using a website (PHP) to send an email using smtp.office365.com or smtp.gmail.com / port 587 (TLS). I have the right username and password so it's not that!

I get a connection error and don't know how to figure out if I need a port opened or if the issue lies somewhere else.

Using Network Utility I can see that port 587 is not open:

[image]

Would I need to open a port for localhost and also my router? I want to know that the port blocking is not the issue.

When I run the following command:

```
nmap -p 587 localhost
```

I get the response:

```
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00017s latency).
Other addresses for localhost (not scanned): ::1 fe80::1
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
587/tcp closed submission
```

Here is the log I am getting from ezPublish:

```
[ Feb 29 2016 20:52:53 ] Unexpected error, the message was : An error occured     
while sending or receiving mail. Failed to connect to the smtp server: smtp.gmail.com:587. 
in /Library/WebServer/Documents/test.com/lib/ezc/Mail/src/transports/smtp/smtp_transport.php
on line 512
```

I get the same error when i use smtp.office365.com as well.

Comment: Show us your mail function.